# Brightness control doesn't work on a Toshiba Satellite L750 with a GeForce GT550

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, brightness

I'm trying to control the brightness of my notebook's screen using NVIDIA X Server but the changes only persist for a few seconds, then turns back to the default settings.

**I've already tried all i've found on the internet about this problem (xorg.conf, grub).

Also have tried changing the brightness from the terminal but it doesn't even recognize the device.

```
$ sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=20
setpci: Warning: No devices selected for "F4.B=20".
```

This is very frustrating because my battery doesn't last as long as it does on windows.

My notebook is a Toshiba Satellite L750 with Geforce GT550.

```
$ lspci | grep nV
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0dec (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem on a vaio laptop with nvidia card

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11543948&postcount=40